# Gorm finder with dynamic argument (part 2)?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have the following domain classes:

```
class AccountRecord {
     List owners // owner of this account
}
```

and

```
class IndividualRecord {
     String uniqueId
     String secondaryId
     List accounts // accounts owned by this individual
}
```

The `owners List` in the `AccountRecord` class stores all the owners of that account by storing maps that contain pairs of each owner's uniqueId and secondaryId. So, an owners list might look like:

```
[
[uniqueId: 1, secondaryId 2] // owner 1 
[uniqueId: 2, secondaryId 3] // owner 2
]
```

Let's say that I want to use GORM to find all `AccountRecord`'s whose owners list contains a map such that the map contains a given IndividualRecord's uniqueId and secondaryId. Basically, given an individual, find all accounts that are owned by the individual. Currently I am doing this but it isn't working(its also returning accounts not owned by the individual for some reason):

```
def accountsOwnedByUser = AccountRecord.where {[uniqueId: someOwner.uniqueId, secondaryId: someOwner.secondaryId] in owners}.list()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no paticular reason why you don't use the standard gorm M:N Relationship, you could just implement it like this:

```
class AccountRecord {
  static hasMany = [owners: IndividualRecord]
}

class IndividualRecord {

  String uniqueId
  String secundaryId

  static belongsTo = AccountRecord
  static hasMany = [accounts: AccountRecord]
}
```

> Basically, given an individual, find all accounts that are owned by the individual

this could then be easily achieved by using the association: `myIndividual.accounts`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest how to do it if not using associations? Appreciate it.